# Automatic Adding Current DateTime In TableField

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am using **SQL SERVER 2005** and i am also newbie to **SQL SERVER**

now i need to know that **is there any way** or any **technique** in SQL SERVER 2005

such that **as soon as i add new record in table** then **current date-time should be added in to any given field of table**.

**Example:**

Suppose i have **`CUSTOMER`** table 
and it has fields say **CustomerID,CustomerName**,....,**DateTime**.
now whenever **new customer added in this table** then **current date-time** should be **automatically** added in to **`DateTime`** Field of **`CUSTOMER`** table.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In SSMS one can set the `Default value or binding` property of the appropriate column of the table property to `getdate()`.

Comment: The getdate() is the local time.
For best practices you can also use getutcdate() this will give back the same time independent of your country/timezone.

Answer (score 15):

You need to add [`default` constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx):

```
alter table MyTable add constraint MyColumnDefault default getdate() for MyColumn;
```

Comment: @Gogolev, thanks for answering.....but i don't know where to write this query and Is there not any way like just setting some property from property window and that's it???

Answer (score 3):

I'm not much of an expert in SQL but you could use TIMESTAMP for this, see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: Timestamp is just an incrementing binary value.  It's primarily intended for row versioning.  From your own link: "The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type."

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should have a look at the timestamp data type:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Check table definition with default value

```
Declare @Table Table 
(
    Id int identity,[Name] varchar(100),CreatedDate DateTime default (Getdate())
)
insert into @Table([Name]) 
values ('yogesh')
insert into @Table ([Name]) 
values ('Bhadauriya')
insert into @Table ([Name]) 
values ('Yogesh Bhadauriya')

select *
From @Table
```